# spring controller returns 404 with post and file with get to generate responseentity

Tags: java, spring, spring-4, spring-restcontroller

I have a controller annotated with @RestController and a mapping returns ResponseEntity with spring 4.3

The method recieves a form with data to generate the file, however if I request the file with a GET method url It generates the file, but if I request the file with a POST method url, spring returns 404

```
@RequestMapping("/request")
@RestController 
MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/notes.do")
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> notes(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Principal principal, NotesForm form) {
        return createResponseEntity(form);
    }
}
```

I get this from weblogic's access.log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/abr/2017:19:11:06 -0500] "GET /app-web/request/notes.do?noteType=DATA&noteContent=HELLO HTTP/1.1" 201 35602
127.0.0.1 - - [05/abr/2017:19:12:29 -0500] "POST /app-web/request/notes.do HTTP/1.1" 404 1322
```

This is the request headers for the get request

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:theme=siirfe-pink;     SIIRFESESS=XKdAssgx6p_kr8OFTRqYQa7IKG8nrIXZr5lO1Ns8lpWE1pFSqfwf!-2083194325!NONE
Host:wlcap1:9102
Pragma:no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.
```

And the request header for the post request

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:103
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Cookie:theme=siirfe-pink; SIIRFESESS=XKdAssgx6p_kr8OFTRqYQa7IKG8nrIXZr5lO1Ns8lpWE1pFSqfwf!-2083194325!NONE
Host:wlcap1:9102
Origin:http://wlcap1:9102
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://wlcap1:9102/app-web/dictaminacion
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
```

This is the response for the get request:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="attachment"; filename="ARCHIVO.DOCX"
Content-Length:35602
Content-Type:application/docx
Date:Thu, 06 Apr 2017 00:39:04 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID:8ac7d542-7157-4b0a-8190-f8e69f03a454-00001af0
X-ORACLE-DMS-RID:0
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

The response for the post request is just an error page.

Is there any way I can get a file from a post request or am I missing something?

According to logs everything seems fine on both cases (the controller runs up until the return from the request in both cases)

Content on the ResponseEntity when post request:

```
201 Created,[B@1e6804c8,{Content-Type=[application/docx], Content-Disposition=[form-data; name="attachment"; filename="ARCHIVO.DOCX"]}
```

Content on the ResponseEntity when get request:

```
201 Created,[B@39cb5a1a,{Content-Type=[application/docx], Content-Disposition=[form-data; name="attachment"; filename="ARCHIVO.DOCX"]}
```

I have not found any error message.

Comment: Please show the entirety of that `/...`. Also note that using `HttpServletRequest`/`Response` is generally discouraged, since Spring provides magic type-safe binding to nearly everything you'd want from them.

Comment: yes. In Spring’s approach to building RESTful web services, HTTP requests are handled by a controller identified by the `@RestController` annotation. use `@RequestParam` or `@PathVariable` to fetch the parameters.

Comment: There is one extra `/` in the URL of the 404 returning call, is that a typo in your question, or the answer to it?

Comment: It was a typo in the question

Comment: Is the difference between `@RequestMapping("/requests")` and `/app-web/request/..` is also a typo? Please fix these, it is makes everything more confusing. With same code it works on my local, cannot make out the reason.

Comment: Yes. On my tests according to my log everything works the same up to building the ResponseEntity. However I get a 404 when I request by post so there must be something about the response that makes spring decide it is an error.

Comment: Oh, so you get to the controller is it? I though endpoint could not be found, maybe then you should share the details of the response entity creation, just debug and see what kinda exception happens within that logic, some exception is mapped to 404 by native spring if you are not doing any custom exception handling,

Comment: I have not been able to find any error message on the logs though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Accept header on the post request fixed the problem. 
I am not sure why it was a problem since it lists */ * (ignore the space, don't know how to get the comment to display it correctly) as the last option, but removing the application/json and text/plain solved the issue